# N(variable name) cannot be resolved to a variable inside a loop

Tags: java, loops

So basically what I am trying is that take T number of testcases. And for each testcase, the first line of input contains a single integer N denoting the size of the array. The second line should contain N space-separated integers denoting the elements of the array. My output should be just displaying the arrays for each testcase. But my code is giving me these two errors-
N cannot be resolved to a variable.
b cannot be resolved to a variable.

I can't figure out where I'm being wrong!

```
Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
        int T=a.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
            int N=a.nextInt();
            int b[]=new int[N];
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
                b[j]=a.nextInt();
            }   
        }
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
                System.out.print(b[j]);//=a.nextInt();
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the second for loop, because N and b are not local to the second loop its value is unknown in that loop, so instead write like this

```
Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
        int T=a.nextInt(); 
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
            int N=a.nextInt();
            int b[]=new int[N];
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
                b[j]=a.nextInt();
            }  
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
                System.out.print(b[j]);//=a.nextInt();
            }  
          
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try and get back to you.